# Cant access the site through the domain name hosted on vps

Tags: node.js, apache, nginx, vps

I have a nodejs website hosted on vps hosting listening on port 8000. I did reverse proxy using nginx to listen all request on port 8000 to port 80 by changing the /etc/nginx/sites-available/default to following:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name www.greenlemonevents.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://67.209.122.170:8000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     }
}
```

where 67.209.122.170 is my remote server ipadress. When i access my site by the ipaddress it is working fine but when i access it by the domain name apache2 pages is shown.  http://www.greenlemonevents.com/ this is showing the apache2 default page and this http://www.greenlemonevents.com:8000/ is working fine. I do not understand why i have to add port when it is working fine here: http://67.209.122.170/ .

I have purged apache2 from the vps server and also removed /var/www/html folder but still it is showing the default ubuntu page.

This is my first time hosting on a vps hosting so pardon if i seem a bit confused... :)

Comment: It's working fine now ?

Comment: No, i m not able to access the site here: http://www.greenlemonevents.com/ 

Default ubuntu page comes here, that is the problem.

Comment: from my side it's working very fine ? i can see the coming soon and the count down timer ! try to clear your browser cache and try again !

Comment: ohh.. completely forgot about it! :P Thanks

Comment: try pinging the domain and make sure it points to the right location,
if it does, try `netstat -ntpl |grep 80` and make sure that nginx is the one that listens.

Comment: It is ok now... i think earlier apache page was there due to /var/www/html folder. As for now it was the cache error